# traversing yaml for Rails app config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, app-config, yaml

I'm trying to load app config yaml - a tree of styles, which I want to traverse:

```
style:
    name: Retro
style:
    name: Nouveau
style:
    name: Plain
```

I'm loading this using the following initializer:

```
STYLES = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/styles.yml")
```

I want to be able to traverse each style using STYLES[:style].each or some similar function.  This is failing,  and STYLES only ever returns the last one listed.  I really don't want to use xml (because it's plain ugly) ... is there a way of making this work with yaml?

if not,  I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The tree of styles yaml is not working the way you want; you'll need to re-structure it to support multiple styles with different names.

```
Retro:
    type: style
Nouvaeu:
    type: style
Plain:
    type: style
```

Think of each block as a new object. Now you can access them using:

```
plain_style = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/styles.yml")['Plain']
plain_style['type']    >>> "style"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more in-dept answer than Jonathan's (which is otherwise correct).

Yaml is format more like json than xml. Yaml and json are designed to be a simple representation of basic but often-used data structures common in most languages (and prevalent in scripting languages). Xml are designed as a markup language and a meta specification with a ton of features to facilitate mixing of different document types.

The most basic, and most often used, containers in Yaml are sequences and maps. In programming languages sequences are often called lists or arrays, and maps are often called dictionaries, hashes, hashmaps or arrays (which is just weird; I'm looking at you PHP).

So your document is equivalent to the yaml/json (valid as both types) document:

```
{"style": {"name": "Retro"}, "style": {"name": "Nouveau"}, "style": {"name": "Plain"}}
```

I you know json or any language with {}-style maps it's fairly easy to see what the problem is. Writting this is in ruby would be:

```
{"style" => ..., "style" => ..., "style" => ...}
```

The last key/value pair overwrites the previous, and they previous are impossible to get at. And therefore you need to change your document format.

## Suggestion 1

Jonathan Julians suggestion is fairly good:

```
Retro:
    type: style
Nouvaeu:
    type: style
Plain:
    type: style
```

## Suggestion 2

I would probably use something like:

```
styles:
    Retro:
    Nouvaeu:
    Plain:
```

Or simply leave "styles" out altogether if it is implied by context.

## Suggestion 3

Another example that is more like xml is to use !!pair

```
!!pair
- style:
    name: Retro
- style:
    name: Nouveau
- style:
    name: Plain
```

This is more or less (depending on the parser/language) equivalent to the data structure:

```
[("style", {"name": "Retro"}), 
 ("style", {"name": "Nouveau"}), 
 ("style", {"name": "Plain"})]
```